# Vim: jump to buffer

Tags: vim

I have 2 tabs with 4 opened buffes:

```
tab1                   tab2   
===================    ===================
|:buf1   |:buf2   |    |:buf3   |:buf4   |
|        |        |    |        |        |
|        |        |    |        |        |
|        |        |    |        |        |
===================    ===================
```

Assume that `:buf4` is currently active. How I can quickly find `:buf2` buffer and jump into? As result I should be in the `tab1` `:buf2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this option:

```
set switchbuf=useopen,usetab
```

you can use:

```
:sb2
```

to jump to buffer number 2 wherever it is currently displayed.

See `:help :sb` and `:help switchbuf`.

Note, however, that windows and tabs are added interaction layers that don't work well with regular buffer commands. With your layout I would simply do `gt` and possibly `<C-w>w`.

Comment: Don't dispair! Vim is buffer-centric and therefore the common layout/tab/file workflows of other editors often are at odds with Vim. Using buffer workflows can be tough for many Vimmers, but remember Vim is a journey. I remember doing a bunch of `switchbuf` stuff before I finally stopped my old workflow and I instead use 1 or 2 splits at a time and avoided tabs completely. I started using `:b` and `:sb` with partial filenames for switching buffers along with other navigation commands. I now jump around between buffers with ease. Enjoy the journey